# PSI Full IO / PSI some IO meaning in htop

Tags: cpu, disk-usage, top, htop

[image: htop screenshot]

In the above screenshot, i examine a large white bar in the CPU Avg chart. Additional, i see PSI full IO/PSI some IO quite large. I assume the white bar is IO wait of some sort.

What exactly does PSI full IO mean? How should i interpret it? How can i find what processes are causing PSI full IO? Is 50% of full IO too large?

Any and all information helpful.

The only related info i could find is https://facebookmicrosites.github.io/psi/docs/overview